# Error- Not-null property references a null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement an api to book an appointment.
i have two entity class and one transaction class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "user_id")
private @Id @GeneratedValue int userid;
private @NotBlank String username;
private @NotBlank String password;
private @NotBlank String first_name;
private @NotBlank String Last_name;
private @NotBlank String disease;
}
```

Doctor class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctors")
public class Doctor implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "doctor_id")
private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) int doctorid;
private @NotBlank String doctor_name;
private @NotBlank String speciality;
```

Appointment class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private @NotBlank int App_id;

private @NotBlank String date;
private @NotBlank String time;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user_id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")
private Doctor doctor_id;

public Appointment(){}

public Appointment( String date, String time,User usr,Doctor doc) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.user_id = usr;
    this.doctor_id = doc;
}
```

Service class

```
` public Status bookappointment(Appointment appointment){
        appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
        return Status.SUCCESS; }`
```

Controller class

```
 @PostMapping("/BookAppointment")
public Status book(@RequestBody Appointment ap){
    System.out.println(ap.toString());
    return appointmentService.bookappointment(ap);
}
```

In postman I am trying to send the post request

```
{
"date":"12/12/2021",
"time":"4:05",
"doctor_id": 4,
 "user_id":14
 }
```

But I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.doctor.appointment.model.Appointment.doctor_id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.doctor.appointment.model.Appointment.doctor_id\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:294)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.doctor.appointment.service.AppointmentServiceImpl.bookappointment(AppointmentServiceImpl.java:24)\r\n\tat com.doctor.appointment.controller.AppointmentController.book(AppointmentController.java:32)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.doctor.appointment.model.Appointment.doctor_id\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:116)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:125)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:289)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:250)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:338)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$$Lambda$1029/1948752857.accept(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:597)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker$$Lambda$1028/1974019244.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 59 more\r\n",
"message": "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.doctor.appointment.model.Appointment.doctor_id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.doctor.appointment.model.Appointment.doctor_id",
"path": "/BookAppointment"
```

What is the problem i am not able to understand?

[My database contains these values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjhbc.png)

Comment: Is it right  that your passing in `4` to represent a Doctor object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Doctor class, your json is expecting a field called `doctor_id` while your class field is called `doctorid`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. The error occurred because I was trying to send the int request to my api.

```
{
"date":"12/12/2021",
 "time":"4:05",
 "doctor_id":{"doctor_id":4},
 "user_id":{"user_id":14}
 }
```

By sending the post request like this i was able to get the response back.